# Unable to change timestamp to date time

Tags: mongodb

{
"meeting": {
"queue": "Waiting in line",
"template": "The Technical Template"
},
"assignee": "John Snow",
"type": "Auto",
"timestamps": [
{
"starttime": 1616358840,
"future": "yes"
},
{
"endtime": 1616361540,
"future": "yes"
}
],
"name": "Chili Piper Technical Call",
"meeting_id": "30075445"
}

Question is:
Based on the configuration, when does the meeting start in PST? What is
the meeting duration?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your question about converting timestamp to date? or about measuring a time period? about storing a date object in mongodb instead of the numerical timestamp? your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

GMT:

Start: Sun Mar 21 2021 20:34:00 GMT+0000

End: Sun Mar 21 2021 21:19:00 GMT+0000

Duration: 45min

PST=GMT-8

or something like this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {
  $project: {
  timestamps: {
    "$mergeObjects": "$timestamps"
  }
}
},
{
  $project: {
  startTime: {
    $toDate: {
      $multiply: [
        {
          $add: [
            "$timestamps.starttime",
            -28800
          ]
        },
        1000
      ]
    }
  },
  endTime: {
    $toDate: {
      $multiply: [
        {
          "$add": [
            "$timestamps.endtime",
            -28800
          ]
        },
        1000
      ]
    }
   }
  }
 },
 {
   $project: {
   _id: 0,
   startTime: 1,
   endTime: 1,
   durationMinutes: {
    $divide: [
      {
        $subtract: [
          "$endTime",
          "$startTime"
        ]
      },
      60000
    ]
   }
  }
 }
 ])
```

result in PST:

```
{
"durationMinutes": 45,
"endTime": ISODate("2021-03-21T13:19:00Z"),
"startTime": ISODate("2021-03-21T12:34:00Z")
}
```

explained:

1. merge the start & end timestamps in single object.
2. Convert the GMT unix timestamp-PST offset(8x60x60)  to ISODate
3. Project the start and end ISODate and calculate the duration in minutes.

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3fcpmxM-NqI)